# What would kill Bitcoin?

Tags: exchange-rate

Other than banning it, what is the biggest risk to the price of Bitcoin? What circumstances may kill Bitcoin or bring it down to less than $10?

Answer (score 5):

No one can determine the effect certain threats will cause, but some "popular" threats are:

- Extreme government regulation.
- Bitcoin losing to a competitor coin.
- Technical attacks, including attacks on protocol (51% attack) or attacks on cryptography.
- Intentional market manipulation to crash the price.

Some factors that can drive these events to be more likely to occur or enable them are:

- Unresolved technical issues, such as blockchain bloat, or transaction limits within blocks.
- End of or diminishing block rewards causing people to abandon mining.
- Increased centralization for whatever reason (advanced technology, zero power costs, etc.)